# Hints get generated past max_hint_window_in_ms

Tags: cassandra

I have cassandra cluster with 8 nodes, where I put 2 of them down.
Cassandra v3.11.11.

Here is my cassandra.yaml config

```
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 3600000
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
```

After one our putting nodes down (max_hint_window_in_ms: 3600000) I expect to get no changes in hints directory but it still running and cassandra generates new hint files.

```
Every 5.0s: ls -lh                        host: Thu Feb  3 18:07:54 2022

total 118M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 Feb  2 08:05 0c197a36-04d0-436a-b4ce-e63742f5fe19-1643789092767-1.crc32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 Feb  2 08:29 0c197a36-04d0-436a-b4ce-e63742f5fe19-1643789477717-1.crc32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.2M Feb  2 08:29 0c197a36-04d0-436a-b4ce-e63742f5fe19-1643789477717-1.hints
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 Feb  2 14:08 0c197a36-04d0-436a-b4ce-e63742f5fe19-1643790595904-1.crc32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20M Feb  2 14:08 0c197a36-04d0-436a-b4ce-e63742f5fe19-1643790595904-1.hints
-rw-r----- 1 root root  31M Feb  3 18:07 0c197a36-04d0-436a-b4ce-e63742f5fe19-1643810952057-1.hints
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 Feb  2 08:29 6ded456d-9d09-4097-8c37-8e46dcd915c4-1643789707920-1.crc32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.9M Feb  2 08:29 6ded456d-9d09-4097-8c37-8e46dcd915c4-1643789707920-1.hints
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 Feb  2 14:08 6ded456d-9d09-4097-8c37-8e46dcd915c4-1643790595910-1.crc32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  22M Feb  2 14:08 6ded456d-9d09-4097-8c37-8e46dcd915c4-1643790595910-1.hints
-rw-r----- 1 root root  35M Feb  3 18:07 6ded456d-9d09-4097-8c37-8e46dcd915c4-1643810952061-1.hints
```

You can see in the output that first hint file was generated on 08:05 2 Feb and still working (current time is 18:07 3 Feb). This continues until my storage gets full and crashes. I have to purge whole hints directory and restart it. It reaches to 5GB of hints directory.

How to stop further generation of hint files? What is the correct configuration/solution for it ?

Comment: Could you please clarify a couple of things - a) is it really 3.11.1, or did you mean 3.11.10 / 3.11.11 ? Can you provide more detail on how 'putting the nodes down' was performed, do you mean the service was stopped? the nodes were decommissioned?

Comment: Andrew, thank you for your reply. version is 3.11.11. I also corrected in the question as well. I just stopped  cassandra service on two nodes. So when I run 'nodetool status' I see all 8 nodes but two of them are down. In the output you also can see that hint files are generated for both nodes, I mean two different UUIDs. Let me know what info I can share more. If I keep two nodes down for more days size of total hint files will get larger and larger. It really depends on how many nodes are down and heavy it is. With provided numbers cluster doesn't work under pressure.

Comment: When running a `nodetool status` are the nodes still there?  May want to run a `nodetool removenode` on them.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinators will store hints again if a node was previously down, came back up then went down again. Every time a node goes down, the timer resets and coordinators will store hints `max_hint_window_in_ms` has expired.

Based on the timestamps you posted, the nodes went down multiple times at:

1. Feb 2 08:05
2. Feb 2 08.29
3. Feb 2 14:08
4. Feb 3 18:07

This indicates that the nodes were going up and down for the timer to reset. You can confirm this by checking the logs on the other 6 nodes.

On a slightly different note, this scenario should highlight to you that your cluster doesn't have enough capacity to tolerate node outages. If your nodes run out of space when other nodes go down even just for a few hours then that's a real problem you need to address and you should review the size of your cluster including the size of the nodes' `hints_directory`. Cheers!